# AngularUI Bootstrap Pager - How to set an icon instead of text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to replace the next and previous text inside of the AngularUI Bootstrap directive with a font awesome icon, but the it is being parsed as text and not HTML

```
<pager previous-text='<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>' total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"></pager>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you post your directive code please -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't, by default, trust anything as `html` so you need to tell it to `trustAsHtml(yourString)`

`trustAsHtml()` is a method on the [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) ($sce) service.

So in your directive, and this is just pseudo as I haven't seen your directive, you need to do something like this:

```
app.directive('pager', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return{
      restrict:'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           var previousTextHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(attrs.previousText);
           // previousTextHtml will now be html
      }
   }
}]);
```

Also, and perhaps a better way of doing this, would be to set a class on your directive.

so rather than pushing `html` through in your `previous-text` attribute, just push through the class you want to set and then whatever you have in your template (assuming you have one) just set the class of an `<i>` to the class in `previous-text`